# SQL execution plan reloaded?

Tags: sql-execution-plan, sql-server-2017, sql-query-store

If a database has Query Store enabled, does SQL 2017 still have separate execution plans that are cleared down and subsequently rebuilt when the instance is restarted, or do they get loaded from the Query Store?

Comment: Yes.  Query Store does not replace the plan cache, it just records what was used.

Comment: @sqillman Thanks for that. Sorry to be pedantic, but I am still not clear whether on restart the plan cache is created from scratch as queries run, or if it is populated from the query store.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look bellow analogy, its associates to SQL Server 2017 Query Store terminology.

> **Query Store size in the database grows until the limit is reached. When that happens, Query Store automatically changes the operation mode to read-only and stops collecting new data, which means that your performance analysis is no longer accurate**.
>
> The default value in SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and SQL Server 2017 (14.x) is 100 MB. Starting with SQL Server 2019 (15.x), the default value is 1 GB.

**Important!**

> **The Max Size (MB) limit isn't strictly enforced.** Storage size is checked only when Query Store writes data to disk. This interval is set by the Data Flush Interval (Minutes) option. If Query Store has breached the maximum size limit between storage size checks, it transitions to read-only mode. **If Size Based Cleanup Mode is enabled, the cleanup mechanism to enforce the maximum size limit is also triggered.**

**Stale Query Threshold (Days)**

> Time-based cleanup policy that controls the retention period of persisted runtime statistics and inactive queries, expressed in days. **By default, Query Store is configured to keep the data for 30 days**, which might be unnecessarily long for your scenario.
>
> ***Avoid keeping historical data that you don't plan to use. This practice reduces changes to read-only status. The size of Query Store data and the time to detect and mitigate the issue will be more predictable.***

[Use Query Store with elastic pool databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/best-practice-with-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15#Configure)

**Conclusion:**
As long as Query Store has been enabled and no reach the limitation of maximum size or retention period (depending on Query Store cleanup policy configuration), then SQL Server will get loaded persisted runtime statistics and inactive query from Query Store when any execution plan is running. Therefore there is no direct influence for Query Store cleanup when SQL Server instance starting/restarting.

Hope this helps!